# SQL SERVER CONNECTION

Tags: c#, sql-server, json, rest, asp.net-web-api

Estoy haciendo un curso sobre Api REST con ASP.net core.
En el archivo **appsettings.json** en el `"ConnectionStrings" :{ "DefaultConnection" : "@" },` Tengo el problema de que no entiendo que cadena pasar porque yo siempre creaba una conexión a la base de datos mediante el Explorador de servidores y mi cadena era algo así `"Data Source=.;Initial Catalog=PeliculasApiv2;Integrated Security=True"`, sin embargo en el ejemplo de la clase se usa algo así `"Server=RENDER2WEB\\SQLEXPRESS; Database=PeliculasApiv2; User ID=renderweb; Password=123456; Trusted_Connection=false; MultipleActiveResulSets=true"`

Ahora si las preguntas:

1. ¿Por qué las cadenas tienen diferentes formas de realizarse si al final apuntan al mismo servidor(se que no son los mismos datos en ambas), por ejemplo parece que Data source es lo mismo que Server?
2. ¿Qué debería poner en mi user y password en la cadena, si mi login a SQL server lo hago mediante Windows Authentication, porque siempre que intento hacer un usuario SQL Server me salen errores?

Answer (score 3):

La *"cadena de conexión"* jamás llega al servidor o al cliente de base de datos como tal. La cadena de conexión –cuando existe– es interpretada por la capa o componente de conexión –también llamado proveedor de base de datos– en busca de los parámetros que necesita para configurarse y poder establecer la conexión de manera exitosa a un motor de base de datos particular.

Puedes llegar a inferir ciertas cosas con solo ver alguna cadena de conexión, pero mi recomendación es que te des siempre una vuelta por la documentación, lo cual te hará conocer no solo el significado exacto de los parámetros que puedes interpretar fácilmente, sino la existencia de otros que te pueden llegar a interesar o que pueden ser la solución a algún problema que enfrentes con la conexión.

Puede ser también que el proveedor de base de datos que usas soporte ambos formatos, ya que algunos términos pueden ser sinónimos de otros, por ejemplo, ADO.NET define `Data Source` y `Server` como sinónimos, por lo que puedes usar cualquiera de los dos.

Puntualizando, a mi mejor manera de ver, la cadena de conexión equivalente a la primera usando la sintaxis de la segunda es:

```
Server=.; Database=PeliculasApiv2; Trusted_Connection=true"
```

Quise dejarte un link a la documentación oficial, suponiendo que estás usando EF sobre ADO.NET, pero no se si hoy estoy espeso con google o Microsoft piensa diferente que yo, lo cierto es que no encontré una buena referencia.

Lo mejor fue esta de [Connection Strings en ASP.NET 4.5](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/aspnet/jj653752(v=vs.110)) (en inglés), que si bien está ya obsoleta, si que puede aclararte el uso de algunos parámetros.

A falta de documentación oficial, lo que si abunda son los [ejemplos de cadenas de conexión](https://www.connectionstrings.com/sqlconnection/) para diferentes escenarios.

Como puedes ver, si tu conexión es mediante la autenticación de windows, no tienes que pasar los parámetros de usuario y contraseña, ya que no son necesarios para establecer la conexión.

Answer (score 1):

Concuerdo con lo que ha respondido el colega jachguate.

nada más para agregar, utiliza esta cadena de conexión con .NET Core y te funcionara bien

```
"Data Source=.\SqlExpress;Initial Catalog=PeliculasApiv2;Integrated Security=True"
```

En datasource puedes poner tanto el nombre de la instancia de SqlServer o la dirección IP separado por una coma luego el puerto a utilizar

Ejemplo : "Data Source=127.0.0.1,1433"